# How can I insert a row if it doesn't already exist while updating multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, case, insert-update

I have a MySQL query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE `Table` SET `Column` = 
    CASE 
      WHEN `Option Id` = '1' THEN 'Apple'
      WHEN `Option Id` = '2' THEN 'Banana'
      WHEN `Option Id` = '3' THEN 'Q-Tip'
    END
```

An my table currently looks like this:

```
Option Id | Column
        1 |      x
        2 |      x
```

I'd like it to result in:

```
Option Id | Column
        1 |  Apple
        2 | Banana
        3 |  Q-Tip
```

But it doesn't insert the Q-Tip row. I've looked up and read a bit about `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and `REPLACE`, but I can't find a way to get those to work with this multiple row update using `CASE`. Do I have to write a separate query for each row to get this to work, or is there a nice way to do this in MySQL?

`Option Id` is not a `Key` itself, but it is part of the `Primary Key`.

**EDIT** Some more info:

I'm programming in PHP, and essentially I'm storing an array for the user. `Option Id` is the key, and `Column` is the value. So for simplicities sake, my table could look like:

```
User Id | Option Id | Value
     10 |         1 | Apple
     10 |         2 |  Shoe
     11 |         1 |  Czar
...
```

That user can easily update the elements in the array and add new ones, then `POST` the array to the server, in which case I'd like to store it in the table. My query above updates any array elements that they've edited, but it doesn't insert the new ones. I'm wondering if there is a query that can take my array from `POST` and insert it into the table without me having to write a loop and have a query for every array element.

Comment: The IDs in your CASE don't match the desired results, typos?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, if `Option_Id` is a primary key:

```
REPLACE INTO `Table` (`Option_Id`, `Column`) VALUES
(1, 'Apple'),
(2, 'Banana'),
(3, 'Q-Tip');
```

The statement means: Insert the given rows or replace the values, if the PK is already existing.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that syntax for inserting multiple rows. It did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does not insert. As there is no such value, it cannot get updated.

I suppose you are normalizing a database by putting in the values already present and now want to add the required mapping for every valid value.

So it would be better to start from scratch and just do INSERTs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. I added some additional info to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could always query the database for entries and then choose update or insert based on yor results

Comment: My goal is to avoid putting a query in a php loop if possible.

Answer (score -1):

I see no point in such updating.
Why don't you have a separate table with option ids and corresponding values, leaving only option ids linked to user ids in this one?